# What free online alternatives are there to FrontPage?

Tags: software-rec, html, web-development, ide, cloud

What's the best free online alternative to Microsoft [FrontPage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage)?

I'm going to make a website for a friend, who will need to be able to edit it himself. All that's needed is something to create/edit simple HTML markup - I'll be doing the styling/CSS separately.

Comment: Are you asking for a WYSIWYG editor or just a text editor?

Comment: I'm looking for a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Oh. See, when someone asks for an alternative to Microsoft FrontPage, I think "something to kill yourself with".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the [Online HTML Editor](http://www.online-html-editor.org/). It is pretty fast and has a full screen mode.

Comment: +1 No frills but nice and simple.

Comment: good enough for some QD work on the go :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/), Mozilla's free online HTML editor.  It allows you to collaborate on projects also.

Comment: I've used Bespin a few times in the past.  Its about the best I could expect out of an online HTML editor, and supports a pretty full feature set of static HTML.  For anything dynamic, you'll need to code it yourself, as with any other tool.

Answer (score 1):

I always go to [www.osalt.com](http://www.osalt.com) to find open-source alternatives. [Here](http://www.osalt.com/frontpage) are the Frontpage alternatives.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

[Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/), the updated version of Nvu is relatively popular.

Comment: Kompozer is not really an online editor, now is it? :)

Comment: Whoops, my eyes just glossed over that and saw 'free FrontPage alternative'

Comment: i didn't vote you down, or i would have said so :)

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's a wrong answer and probably should be voted down.

Answer (score -3):

Well, it's not online, but it is free: Microsoft's own [Sharepoint Designer 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/default.aspx), which is basically the Office 2007 version of FrontPage.  They set it free earlier this year, if I recall.  BTW, it is a vast improvement over FrontPage 2003.

Comment: -1 question asks for 'online solution', and a re-bedged frontpage is not really an alternative.